# Sublime Text 2 - How to open a file from open folders using the command pallet?

Tags: command, sublimetext

I want to open a file using some kind of fuzzy searching, and I'm pretty sure I've seen this functionality inside Sublime Text, but for some reason I can't find any mention of this anywhere.

I want to open the command pallet and be able to type a file name in there, and if the file is close, It will open the file for me, if it's open, it will activate it's window and group.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I see you already found ctrl+p, but the [original announcement](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1464) of this feature has some good information on usage so I thought I'd post it.

> The biggest change here is that the Ctrl+P dialog has been reworked into a more general "Goto Anything" popup. From this, you can:
>
> Type, to search through files (open files, recently closed files, and files in open folders)
>
> @foo, to search through symbols in the current file
>
> :foo, to go to the given line number
>
> #foo, to do a fuzzy search in the current file for foo
>
> These can be combined: "foo@bar" will search for the file that best matches "foo", and go to the symbol in that file that best matches "bar". "foo:100" would go to line 100 of the same file. You can use this to preview a location in another file, then hit escape to go back to where you where.

Comment: I would like to add that tutsplus has a wicked tutorial for workflow with the Sublime Text editor.
https://tutsplus.com/course/improve-workflow-in-sublime-text-2/
This also talks about the file switching with Ctrl+P