# Sublime Text 3 Command palette for folder opening

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want to setup a plugin which allows a new command palette to list the folders inside a certain directory. When user types the name of these folders I want to fire a new window which opens the folder as the menu option File>Open Folder.. does.

EG Folder /Client would be my directory so it could list ClientA, ClientB, ClientC in the command palette.

Just wondering if this is possible I couldn't find anything through the sublime text API or when I Googled around.

Closest I found was the following but its really different
[Sublime Text 2 - How to open a file from open folders using the command pallet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632549/sublime-text-2-how-to-upen-a-file-from-open-folders-using-the-command-pallet)